# Can Select options have Multiple Values?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, elementor

I'm wondering if it's possible to have code where the Select option has 2 different value (which effect 2 different things)

Basically, I'm trying to create an option where depending on the select choice, it changes the price and also changes the link that pressing the button will go to.

I found this code on one of the posts here and it works perfectly, but I'm looking to add a Price in between the select menu and the button which is also effected by the select choice.

Eg.

1 Year Only - $50 [Button links to correct purchase link]

Subscription (Billed Annually) - $45/pa [Button links to correct purchase link]

Sorry if i'm not explaining it very well.

```
<select id="menu">
<option selected="selected" disabled="">Please choose an option</option>
<option value="https://checkout-1-year">1 Year</option>
<option value="https://checkout-subscription">Subscription (Billed Annually)</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="goBtn" value="Purchase">

<script type="text/javascript">
var goBtn = document.getElementById("goBtn");
var menu = document.getElementById("menu");

goBtn.onclick = function() {
window.location = menu.value;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can't have two values, but what you can do is set the `value` and a `data-` attribute, which can store any string you like and then be retrieved using the [data-* Attribute API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Here's an example:

```js
const list = document.getElementById("menu");
console.log(list.options[1].value, list.options[1].dataset.value);
console.log(list.options[2].value, list.options[2].dataset.value);
```

```html
<select id="menu">
  <option selected="selected" disabled="">Please choose an option</option>
  <option value="https://checkout-1-year" data-value="something">1 Year</option>
  <option value="https://checkout-subscription" data-value="something else">Subscription (Billed Annually)</option>
</select>
```